# Can't access Task.Delay() on xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am trying to add a task delay and I know how to do it from many other questions answered on S.O. but It just doesn't work on xamarin...

I am using the below.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

but I keep getting an error: 'Task' does not contain a definition for 'delay'

I am using Xamarin Studio Community, Version 6.3 (Build 864) on Mac.

Comment: You could have at least posted the Xamarin version you are using and the .NET framework target

Comment: What is the .NET framework target?

Comment: why the negative votes? this is a legitimate question, been stuck on this for past hour now.

Comment: `Task.Delay` is only available in .NET 4.5 and higher. Go to your project properties and check which version of .NET you are targeting.

Comment: Okay so mine is .NET 4.0... Thanks for at getting me somewhere.. so how do I change it to 4.5 or higher? I am just a student here so forgive me for my inexperience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Task.Delay` is available on .NET 4.5 and later.

I believe you are using earlier version of .NET (or comparable version of Mono). You might try looking for `TaskEx.Delay`, as it is back-port of this functionality from .NET 4.5 to .NET 4

You have to add the Microsoft.Bcl.Async package from NuGet to access TaskEx.Delay